# Dynamically Creating Calendar Through InnerHTML Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, onload

Originally I had this code working  but I then decided not to dynamically create the table every time but instead just the text it needs to populate within the table.  I do not know if this is the most efficient way of creating a calendar dynamically so also let me know if there are better methods (I prefer keeping it to JavaScript).  I cannot figure out why my table is no longer being created so any help would be much appreciated.

HTML-

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Dynamically create the calendar -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js">
    window.onload = function(){
      var cal = new Calendar();
      cal.drawCalendar();
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Create the calendar object -->
    <table class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <th class="header" colspan="7"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="headerdays">Sun</td>
        <td class="headerdays">Mon</td>
        <td class="headerdays">Tue</td>
        <td class="headerdays">Wed</td>
        <td class="headerdays">Thu</td>
        <td class="headerdays">Fri</td>
        <td class="headerdays">Sat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class ="days">
    </tr>
</table>

    <!-- Add buttons to change the calendar month -->
    <button class="calButton" onclick="cal.prevMonth()"><span> Prev </span></button>
    <button class="calButton" onclick="cal.nextMonth()"><span> Next </span></button>

</body>
```

JavaScript -

```
// these are labels for the days of the week
cal_days_labels = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

// these are human-readable month name labels, in order
cal_months_labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                 'October', 'November', 'December'];

// these are the days of the week for each month, in order
cal_days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

// this is the current date
cal_current_date = new Date(); 

//Constructor function for Calendar
function Calendar(month, year) {
  this.month = (isNaN(month) || month == null) ? cal_current_date.getMonth()   : month;
  this.year  = (isNaN(year) || year == null) ? cal_current_date.getFullYear() : year;

}

//Generates the needed HTML for the calendar
Calendar.prototype.generateHTML = function(){

  // get first day of month
  var firstDay = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1);
  var startingDay = firstDay.getDay();

  // find number of days in month
  var monthLength = cal_days_in_month[this.month];

  // Compensate for leap year
  if (this.month == 1) { // February only!
    if((this.year % 4 == 0 && this.year % 100 != 0) || this.year % 400 == 0){
      monthLength = 29;
    }
  }

  // Fill in month and year for header
  var monthName = cal_months_labels[this.month];
  document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].innerHTML =  monthName + "&nbsp;" + this.year;

  // fill in the days
  var html += '';
  var day = 1;
  // this loop is for is weeks (rows)
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    // this loop is for weekdays (cells)
    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { 
      html += '<td class="day">';
      if (day <= monthLength && (i > 0 || j >= startingDay)) {
        html += day;
        day++;
      }
      html += '</td>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';
    // stop making rows if we've run out of days
    if (day > monthLength) {

      break;
    }
  }

  //Write the days to the screen
  document.getElementsByClassName("days")[0].innerHTML = html;

}

//Writes the calendar to the screen
Calendar.prototype.drawCalendar = function() {
  //Generates the HTML and write HTML to screen
  this.generateHTML();
}

//Sets the calendar to previous month
Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
  //Set the month back by one
  this.month = (this.month != 0) ? this.month - 1 : 11;
  this.year  = (this.month != 11) ? this.year : this.year - 1;
  this.drawCalendar();
}

//Sets the calendar to next month
Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
  //Set the month forward by one
  this.month = (this.month != 11) ? this.month + 1 : 0;
  this.year  = (this.month != 0) ? this.year : this.year + 1;
  this.drawCalendar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different `<script>` block for your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var cal = new Calendar();
        cal.drawCalendar();
    }
    ...
</script>
```